# How to share data (display same data) between two portlets in liferay?

Tags: session, jsf, liferay, javabeans, portlet

I have a scenario where user have two screens one for creating entity (like a new book) and the other for viewing that newly created entity.

The user opens both screens and create a new entity and want to see that entity on the other screen.

The entity is being saved into a list not database there fore,both screen are required to share same list of entity how this can be done ?

What is the best (performance focused so that user don't see any lag) way to implement this in life-ray.

**Note:**The existing system is extremely complex and is built using liferay and prime-faces mainly, This should be done without refreshing the viewing screen.
This is only for one signed in user and has to be done using JSF(Prime-faces)

Comment: performance focused? So that 1000000 users can do it at the same time? Or that the same user doesn't see any lag? Actually, I don't understand the "best" here at all. You tag with "jsf" - is this mandatory technology or just an idea? What do "session" and "javabeans" tags mean? Please edit, as questions for "the best" typically are opinionated and risk being closed on stackoverflow.

Comment: You can invoke AJAX call for adding new record and refresh portlet using `Liferay.Portlet.refresh(portletId);` on successful call.

Comment: can you please have a look the question again i have modified it.

Comment: Does your both screens are in single portlet or these are two different portlets?

Comment: they are two different portlets .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used **primfaces** "poll" to resolve the issue.